# Какой паттерн применить?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

[image: diagram]
Реализую MVC. В классах потомках получается слишком много повторяющегося кода. Вынести в родительский класс нет возможности. На самом деле потомков подразумевается больше, чем изображено на диаграмме. И как-то все под копирку создаются. Понимаю,что нужно что-то с архитектурой делать, но не могу определиться.

Comment: Композиция (если правильно помню названия, гугл говорит, что я неправильно что-то говорю) / промежуточный класс?

Comment: Да, это композиция (агрегация). Но вот что сделать, чтобы в классах-потомках меньше повторяющегося кода было?

Comment: Может быть абстрактные классы использовать?

Comment: @xlmax, видимо я неправильно все-таки назвал. То, что я понимаю под композицией:

    class Controller_Main
    {
        public $recurrentHandler;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->recurrentHandler = new RecurrentCodeHandler;
        }
        //магия, перенаправляющая запросы к несуществующем методам на recurrentHandler
    }

В этом случае повторяющийся код остается, но по минимуму (конструктор + магия). В идеале же нужен просто класс-прослойка между Controller и наследниками, в котором и будет тот код.  
Если приведете конкретный пример, будет легче.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если изучить существующие реализации в частности PHP фрейморки.
То там же все просто: наследники они же конкретные реализации контроллеров располагаются кучкой классов, которые наследуются от базового виртуального. При обработке запроса, в ход вступает класс Dispatcher, который определяет с помощью роутера необходимый класс контроллер и создает его с помощью обычной фабрики. Диспетчер обладает всей необходимой информацией о контролерах и работает только с базовым класом. В php проще вызывать методы, которые не объявлены в интерфейсе. Поэтому по всем правилам тебе необходимо определять действия не тупым списком index, add, update, delete. А методом callAction( string method, ...  )
который определить в Базовом классе. и который будет смотреть локальную базу всех доступных действий и вызывать необходимое. Локальная база как и сами действия уже определяются внутри каждой конкретной реализации контроллера.

В C++ я думаю идеально подойдут делегаты в качестве действий и в качестве локального хранилища, тоже в базовом классе `map<string, ControllerResponse (*ControllerActionDelegate) ( ControllerRequest )>` Где ControllerRequest, ControllerResponse -- динамические структры, в которые можно помещать необходимые данные

PS: Простите, если я что-то напутал. давно на C++ не писал.

В рамках паттернов. Полезным будет: [Шаблон делегирования](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80)